# What is this weird pimple on my cat's skin?

Tags: cats, skin-condition, hairloss

I have 2 questions to ask

1. I was looking for fleas and found this. What is this called? Is it related  to fleas?
   [image]

   2. The condition that the cat has good coat on his lower / belly / heart side and poor coat on the upper back, related to fleas? how can a cat have poor coat at the one side and better and long coat on the other side?

Comment: is this on your cats belly? if it is it is a nipple.

Comment: If you search a little more you should find another 7 of those ...

Comment: damn, that is a male cat man

Comment: If you have multiple questions, please split them off into individual questions so the answers can address the relevant points. I suggest removing point 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost all mamals do have nipples just like it is in human female/males.

The number of mamarian nipples in cats are normaly 6 to 8 but it can vary from 4 to 10 and the numbers are not always even.

More about this here:https://kittyclysm.com/cat-nipples/ if you google cat nipples you will find a lot of information about it.

So the answer to your question is this is not related to fleas it is just mamarian nipples and both female and male cats have them.

(mamarian nipples are the same as breast nipples)