# What is this bump on my cat?

Tags: cats, health

She has this bump but it’s sticking pretty far out, I’m a little concerned. She started wiggling around when I tried looking at it. It’s too far from her stomach to be a nipple. Should I take her to the vet or no?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this weird pimple on my cat's skin?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20309/what-is-this-weird-pimple-on-my-cats-skin)

Comment: i am 99% sure that is a nipple,if you want it confirmed take your cat to the vet or take a look on the picture in the linked Q&A.

Comment: Look for the other nipples - you should find 8 in total (normally) and they should be in similar places on the left & right sides of the cat's belly. Then you'll know if this one matches with the pattern.